# Call exported method in react native

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, react-native, native-module

I want to create a view in Objective C and use in react native, but don't know how to do this
Here's my code:
Obj-C:

```
#import "DGTAuthenticateButtonView.h"
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "UIView+React.h"
#import <DigitsKit/DigitsKit.h>

@implementation DGTAuthenticateButtonView

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
- (UIView *) view {
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  [button setTitle:@"REGISTER" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  return button;

}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(authenticate) {
  Digits *digits = [Digits sharedInstance];
  DGTAuthenticationConfiguration *configuration = [[DGTAuthenticationConfiguration alloc] initWithAccountFields:DGTAccountFieldsDefaultOptionMask];
  configuration.phoneNumber = @"+345555555555";
  [digits authenticateWithViewController:nil configuration:configuration completion:^(DGTSession *newSession, NSError *error){
  }];

}

@end
```

I want to call `authenticate` in TouchableOpacity but it didn't work :(

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';



var requireNativeComponent = require('requireNativeComponent');

var DGTAuthenticateButtonView = requireNativeComponent('DGTAuthenticateButtonView', DGTAuthenticateButtonView);

class TestProj extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
                onPress={() => DGTAuthenticateButtonView.authenticate()}
            />

        )
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestProj', () => TestProj);
```

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that's you're mixing 2 different concepts here.

You can either create a [Native UI Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) - a native view that you can use as a component in your RN `render` functions; or you can create a [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) - a module which allows you to add native functionality and call it from your JS code, this module doesn't have a view.

As far as I can tell (you didn't include the code for your `RCTViewManager` subclass), you're attempting to create a `Native UI Components` on the native side (which returns a view), but not using it as such in your JS (not used as a component in your `render`). You should also know that you can't simply call methods directly on your native views like you're trying to do here.

**I suggest that you use one of following solutions:**

1. If you really need a customized native UI - follow the instruction for creating a `Native UI Component` and then use your component in
   your render function. You can then communicate the button press using a prop
   that is mapped to a callback (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#events) about events from native to JS).
2. If you don't need a custom UI (you want to keep using `TouchableOpacity` as in your example) you can follow the instruction to create a `Native Module`. You'll then be able to call your `authenticate` method statically as you were trying to do here to perform only the native logic. You can even modify the `authenticate` method to receive additional parameters - a reject/resolve promise or a callback to notify the JS when it's done.

Comment: I follow the fb sample code for 2nd solution and it works. Thanks so much :D